# How Should I Prove that the Localization of Quotients Commute from here?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, exact-sequence, localization, module-isomorphism

Let S be a multiplicatively closed subset of R, M an R-module, and N a submodule of M. I want to prove that:

S$^{-1}$(M/N) is isomorphic to (S$^{-1}$M)/(S$^{-1}$N).

**Attempt:** Since $0$$\rightarrow$ N$\xrightarrow{f}$ M$\xrightarrow{g}$ M/N$\rightarrow$ $0$ is exact, then I can show that $0$$\rightarrow$ S$^{-1}$N$\xrightarrow{f^{‘}}$ S$^{-1}$M$\xrightarrow{g^{‘}}$ S$^{-1}$M/N$\rightarrow$ $0$ is exact as well. However, I don’t know how to go from here. That is,

**Question**: How can I prove that S$^{-1}$(M/N) is isomorphic to (S$^{-1}$M)/(S$^{-1}$N) from here?

Your help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Well, this is exactly the exactness of $0 \to S^{-1}N \to S^{-1}M \to S^{-1}(M/N) \to 0$.

Comment: @psl2Z I meant to say I could prove the sequence you wrote. I just edited my post. However, the question remains I don’t know how to go from here to prove the isomorphism. Will appreciate any hint or suggestions you can give.

Comment: If a sequence of modules $0\to M'\to M\to M''\to 0$ is exact, then $M''\cong M/M'$

Comment: @JerryScott Yes, I know. If I can prove this, I will be able to solve the one I posted. How can I prove this?

Comment: It is the first isomorphism theorem for modules, you can find a proof in most commutative algebra textbooks I think

Comment: @JerryScott I know from the first theorem of Isomorphism of modules that if $\phi$$\in$Hom(M,N), then M/Ker$\phi$ is isomorphic to im$\phi$. However, I don’t seem to know how to apply that in this case. Does that mean I should treat M$^{‘}$ as  Ker$\phi$?

Answer (score 0):

Let $0\to M'\xrightarrow{i} M\xrightarrow{e} M''\to 0$ be an exact sequence of modules. Then know that:

- $i$ is injective because its kernel is the image of $0\to M'$, which is the zero submodule of $M'$.
- $e$ is surjective because its image is the kernel of $M''\to 0$, which is all $M''$.

The exactness in $M$ says that $\operatorname{ker}e=\operatorname{im}i$, hence the first isomorphism theorem yields $M''\cong M/\operatorname{im}i$, as $e$ is surjective. But $i$ is injective, so $M'\cong \operatorname{im}i$: you can then view $M'$ itself as a submodule of $M$ and write $M/M'\cong M''$.